# How to save a view

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to save a view in QGIS? In other words, you can "zoom to last" view; how about, after getting your view area, scale, and shape the way you want it, save that view to return to?

Comment: Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The built-in Bookmarks (View->New Bookmark) is probably what you want.